# Windows server Essentials fault by not find correctly named server certificate

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, certificate-authority, windows-server-essentials

I have a problem with CA configuration on AD windows server 2012r2. It manifests itself by error with starting "windows server essentials services".
I figure out there is something wrong into: hklm>software>microsoft>windows server>identity
The CAName should be different in my opinion.
Now, it has the "NAME" as DOMAIN-SRV-DC2-CA, instead of name in Certification Authority: “company-SRC-DC2-CA”
Question. Should I change CANAME in regedit for one that is in a Certification Authority?

I will be grateful for any tips.